# Notice given and used had to use sick leave in last week

Tags: salary, australia

I'm working in New South Wales, Australia. I have given 2 months notice and now down to my last week and became ill. I have a doctors certificate, but can they hold any pay back from me as it is two days before I finish with the company?

Comment: Hi Cindy, welcome to The Workplace! Can you please clarify what "NSW" means? Also, have you consulted your employment handbook or any other company documentation on employment? the more information you can provide, the more accurate the answers. Hope this helps!

Comment: New South Wales which is part of Australia I believe.

Answer (score 4):

I'm somewhat unclear what you're concerned about with respect to holding back pay, but assuming that you had enough sick days accrued to cover your period of absence and assuming that you have informed them that you're using your sick days and complied with any relevant policies in place regarding sick leave (such as providing them with your doctor's note), then no, they cannot take anything from your final pay and entitlements.

If your employer does things correctly, your last week should be paid out of your accrued sick leave, and then your final paycheck should include any wages owed plus any accrued annual leave (but not sick leave; unless you work in timber, coal, or whatever 'Stevedoring' is) that you have, plus any other accrued entitlements.  This is a legal requirement:

http://www.fairwork.gov.au/ending-employment/notice-and-final-pay/final-pay

If, on the other hand, you do **not** have enough sick leave to cover the absence (or you fail to comply with any relevant policies governing the use of sick leave) and you also don't have enough annual leave to make up the difference, then you may have to have unpaid leave recorded for those days.  In which case it would come out of your final pay.

Comment: For the record, a stevedore is a person who loads and unloads ships

Comment: @aroth - This is a very good answer.  Besides the very specific legal requirements the overall answer really can be applied to anyone.

Comment: Stevedoring is what lumpers do.